# unfortunately app has stopped when click on button

Tags: android

**First question**

I am a beginner to the Android Studio. I want to create SMS app. I make two EditText one for number and other for text in xml and also one send button which is shown below.

so when I clicked on send button then its show `unfortunately app has stopped`. there is no error in the program.

**Second question**

what is actually the reason for that kind of problem?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etMassage;
    EditText etTelNr;

    int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 1;

    String SENT = "SMS_SEND";
    String DELIVERD = "SMS_DELIVERD";

    PendingIntent sentp1, deliverdP1;
    BroadcastReceiver sendsmsReciver, smsDeliveredReciver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etMassage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMassage);
        etTelNr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTelNr);

        sentp1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        deliverdP1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERD), 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        sendsmsReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                switch (getResultCode()) {

                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS sent ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "generic failure ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO SERVICE ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO PDU ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " NO RADIO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        smsDeliveredReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS DELIVERED ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS CANCELLED ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(sendsmsReciver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
        registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReciver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERD));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(smsDeliveredReciver);
        unregisterReceiver(sendsmsReciver);
    }

    public void btn_SendSMS_OnClick(View v) {

        String message = etMassage.getText().toString();
        String telNr = etTelNr.getText().toString();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);


        } else {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(telNr, null, message, sentp1, deliverdP1);
        }
    }
}
```

*xml code for button*

```
<Button
    android:text="Send" 
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="send" />
```

Comment: In button xml, there is android:onclick="send". In Activity we should have same method name as send.
void send(View view) { 
}

Comment: use android:text="btn_SendSMS_OnClick" instead of android:text="Send" in xml file

Answer (score 0):

you are calling a wrong function in the OnClick event of the button
it should be like this

```
<Button
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="btn_SendSMS_OnClick" />
```

hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: yes, it will. maybe the error is with the code. you can debug code and put a break point on btn_sendSMS_OnClick function definition